# Protoc.py compiles files differently depending on where it is called from

Tags: powershell, protocol-buffers, protobuf-python

If protoc.py is called from powershell, the compiled file is missing about half of the code as opposed to when protoc.py is called from natively from python. I have a powershell script and a python script. My aim is to remove the python script so I only need the powershell script.

My python script is here:

```
PythonScript.py

import os
from grpc_tools.protoc import main

os.chdir("<MyProtoDirectory>")

main([
    '--proto_path=.',
    '--python_out=<MyOutputDirectory>',
    '--grpc_python_out=<MyOutputDirectory>',
    '<MyProto'])
```

and my powershell script is here:

```
PowershellScript.ps1

$tmp = (Get-Location).tostring()
Set-Location -Path ('<MyProtoDirectory>')

try {
  python '...\protoc.py' `
    --proto_path='.' `
    --python_out='<MyOutputDirectory>' `
    --grpc_python_out="<MyOutputDirectory>" `
    "<MyProto>"

}
finally {
  Set-Location -Path $tmp
}
```

I am calling main in python, and the script in powershell, so I modified protoc.py to be:

```
protoc.py

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #proto_include = pkg_resources.resource_filename('grpc_tools', '_proto')
    #sys.exit(main(sys.argv + ['-I{}'.format(proto_include)]))
    a = main(sys.argv[1:])
    print(a)
    sys.exit()
```

where I have commented out the altered lines. When I run the python script, I get the result:

```
outcome_pb.py        67kb
outcome_pb_grpc.py   77kb
```

When I run the powershell script, I get the result:

```
outcome_pb.py        28kb
outcome_pb_grpc.py   77kb
```

The powershell output outcome_pb.py is incorrect and cannot be run, whereas the python outcome is good. It is worth noting outcome_pb_grpc is identical when run using either the powershell script or the python script. Futhermore, I can write a new powershell script that simply calls the python script:

```
python .\PythonScript.py
```

and this leads to the same issue. I need both outcome_pb.py and outcome_pb_grpc.py for my application. Why is this happening?

Comment: I suspect (!) that you're catching different versions of `protoc` (and thus its internal plugin for python that effects `python_out`). Google has changed how protobuf code is generated for Python quite considerably and this would explain the file size differences and why you can't compile stub code generated by a different `protoc` compiler version. gRPC has not changed (as significantly). For example, see [Changes made 06-May-2022](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/news/2022-05-06). But there was also a significant change (somewhere) between e.g. 3.14.0 and 3.20.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like DazWilkin said in a comment, it is likely that there is a difference in either the `grpcio_tools` library or the Python version you end up using.

To test, you can use some prints:

```
 import sys
 import grpc_tools.protoc
 print("Python version: %s" % sys.version)
 print("grpcio_tools path: %s" % grpc_tools.protoc.__file__)
```

and compare the output between the working and not-working case.

Comment: Thank you, the version of grpcio_tools that seemed to fail was 1.50.0, rolling back to 1.48.1 allowed me to compile the files correctly.